# udev rule for HID scanner permissions

Tags: permissions, scanner, udev

I am adding a `udev` rule to enable access to a HID **barcode** scanner to enable users to gain access.

The rule:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{product}=="Metrologic Scanner", GROUP:="myUsername"
```

was added to: `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules`

I would like to use a GROUP name that is not installation / configuration dependent.  Is there a standard group name that is conventionally used that includes all user accounts?

Answer (score 1):

- The standard group is `scanner`.

  References:

  1. [Debian: Scanner](https://wiki.debian.org/Scanner)
  2. [Ubuntu Wiki: Scanning HowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ScanningHowTo)
- No, AFAIK there is no group that have all users by default. You have add all users to `users` group explicitly.

  May be it's a good alternative to set the mode instead `MODE:="0666"`